# Scope on Polymorpic model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, scope, polymorphic-associations

Is it possible to make a scope for a polymorphic model in the following case?

I have a polymorphic model named Mutations.

```
class Mutation < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :mutationable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

A Mutation belongs to both models TimeRegistration and SickRegistration. A TimeRegistration and a  SickRegistration (Mutationable) belongs_to a User.

```
class SickRegistration < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :mutations, as: :mutationable
end

class TimeRegistration < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :mutations, as: :mutationable
end
```

I want to create a scope for the Mutation whereby i can retrieve a collection of Mutations by a given user name. I have more scopes already on the Mutation model, so this one must be joined with the other used scopes (used for filtering).

So something like this on the Mutation Model:

```
 scope :with_name, -> (name) { joins(mutationable: :user).where('users.name = ?', name) }
```

This won't work. I've also tried to make a delegate on the Mutation model and to make a custom SQL Query with multiple joins on the mutationable models, but without success. I think there must be an (more easy) way to do this, but i can't find any good examples or ansewers for this problem.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please share your association between user and TimeRegistration, user and SickRegistration,  SickRegistration and Mutation, TimeRegistration and  Mutation

Comment: Edited: Added the association between user and TimeRegistration and user and SickRegistration

Comment: check my solution

Answer (score 0):

#### ******TRY THIS*****

**Mutation.rb**

```
belongs_to :sick_registation, ->{where(mutations: {mutationable_type: 'SickRegistation'})},
foreign_key: 'mutationable_id'

belongs_to :time_registation, ->{where(mutations: {mutationable_type: 'TimeRegistation'})},
foreign_key: 'mutationable_id'

scope :with_name, ->(name){ 
  joins(sick_registation: :user).where(user:{name: name}) +
  joins(time_registation: :user).where(user:{name: name})
}
```

**Explanation**:
There is no direct relation between your polymorphic relation and user.
So, I am joining the results of individual associated i.e sick and time.

Comment: Adding the results by + is resulting in an array instead of an Active Record. Additional scopes can't be performed on an array.

Comment: @RonaldBoekhoudt It gives ActiveRecord relation only. no worries.check once

Comment: I have multiple scopes on the model. After this scope, another scope is performed. This can't be done because the result of joining individual results is an Array.
NoMethodError (undefined method `till_date' for []:Array):

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
 scope :with_name, -> (name) { where(mutationable: User.where(name: name)) }
```

> > edited. added )

**Edit2:**

My bad for my "wrong quick solution" due to not reading carefully enough, but I see the question has been edited and it is more clear now.

Knowing what you want to achieve I would suggest a different approach. Mutable should not be hardcoded looking at specific models because it will limit the flexibility provided by the polymorphic associations and will break 'Law of Demeter'

To get a collection of mutations of a particular set of XXXRegistrations I would do:

a. Use STI so the queriable XXXRegistrations, extend a Registration model. Add a scope to filter by user.

```
SickRegistration < Registration
```

b. Query Registration for user and then get the mutations

```
Registration.for_user(user).joins(:mutations)
```

Comment: It will need to be Rails 4+

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Query is looking for a model User (mutationable_type) in the mutations table, but there is no link from Mutation to User, only to TimeRegistration and SickRegistration are mutationable_types.

Comment: This will not work. If you want to query a nested association you have to pass it as: `where(mutationable: { user: { name: name } })`